# Getting a Brother HL-2250DN Printer to work over Ethernet

Tags: 13.04, printing, brother

For 3 years I had an HP OfficeJet G55 running on Ubuntu - great! loved it, all was simple and just worked ... then it broke.  I ordered a new printer a Brother HL-2250DN.

I've got the drivers from Brother, so USB is okay. Networked... for the rest of my laptops and computers... no it is using gutenprint - nice project but printing at a resolution of 100 is just diabolical. How I wish I could just go back to my OfficeJet G55.

I know this is due to hardware manufacturers, but how do I just use my printer?

Comment: Got it working networked with Generic PCL6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic

Even Duplex works! However, I still stand by my comments that it should not be this difficult - I believe we (the linux community) have it sorted with most internal hardware now, installing Ubuntu is a breeze - if we can crack this issue we will be leagues ahead.

Comment: Could you share the steps you followed to make it work?

Comment: Braiam, on 13.04 - go to add printer, I click networked printer, with nothing in the search box I click 'find' and wait for it to appear. Then select it and when choosing the driver, choose Generic : PCL6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic pxlcolor - all works fine for me. Use the same procedure and driver for USB connected Printer

Comment: Arg! I hate when I'm so ambiguious. In the space below, it says "Your Answer", you can write it there.

Answer (score 7):

Got it working networked with Generic PCL6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic Even Duplex works - go to add printer, I click networked printer, with nothing in the search box I click 'find' and wait for it to appear. Then select it and when choosing the driver, choose Generic : PCL6/PCL XL Printer Foomatic pxlcolor - all works fine for me. Use the same procedure and driver for USB connected Printer

Comment: Thanks, worked for me on 14.10 with one wrinkle: http://askubuntu.com/a/709896/130331

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 14.10 I did the same as @matthew-hudson in [his answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/338103/130331), but with one wrinkle. I had to use the listing for the printer with an IP address next to it (there were two listings: one with and one without an IP address). The listing with an IP address took longer to appear in the list than the one without.

[image: ...]

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me in 16.04

- print the Printer's settings (pressing the Go button 3x in less than 2s)
- find the printer's IP address on the last page
- go to System settings->Printers
- click “Add”
- select “LPD/LPR Host or Printer”
- enter the printer’s IP address as Host
- enter “PCL_P1” as Queue

Answer (score -1):

Brother has released an autoconfig script for all his printers which downloads the appropriate drivers and installs/configures the printer either USB or networked

http://welcome.solutions.brother.com/bsc/public_s/id/linux/en/faq_prn.html#f00104

Answer (score -1):

Set the printer for HP LaserJet for a trouble free existence.

The printer has a browser based admin system. Just all up it's IP in a browser on the network. The default password for the settings screens is "access".

In the Printer Settings if you set emulation to HP LaserJet, then do a network discovery for printer, it should be found as a laserjet.  I used the vanilla HP LaserJet driver from the available drivers and the thing works flawlessly.